# How can I insert daily values back into hourly dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I resample hourly data to daily, then I want feed the daily values back into the hourly dataframe:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

hours = []
starttime = datetime.now()
for i in range(26):
    starttime += timedelta(hours=1)
    #print(starttime)
    hours.append(starttime)

data = np.random.rand(len(hours))
df = pd.DataFrame(index=hours)
df['Count']=data

df_d = df.resample('D').sum().ffill()
print(df)
print(df_d)

                               Count
2021-03-25 11:39:53.836617  0.198908
2021-03-25 12:39:53.836617  0.527821
2021-03-25 13:39:53.836617  0.188465
2021-03-25 14:39:53.836617  0.959682
2021-03-25 15:39:53.836617  0.259011
2021-03-25 16:39:53.836617  0.371357
2021-03-25 17:39:53.836617  0.378044
2021-03-25 18:39:53.836617  0.893711
2021-03-25 19:39:53.836617  0.117638
2021-03-25 20:39:53.836617  0.615468
2021-03-25 21:39:53.836617  0.967704
2021-03-25 22:39:53.836617  0.323810
2021-03-25 23:39:53.836617  0.982572
2021-03-26 00:39:53.836617  0.634717
2021-03-26 01:39:53.836617  0.649848
2021-03-26 02:39:53.836617  0.817843
2021-03-26 03:39:53.836617  0.085714
2021-03-26 04:39:53.836617  0.260640
2021-03-26 05:39:53.836617  0.957139
2021-03-26 06:39:53.836617  0.983080
2021-03-26 07:39:53.836617  0.433029
2021-03-26 08:39:53.836617  0.570552
2021-03-26 09:39:53.836617  0.854964
2021-03-26 10:39:53.836617  0.506302
2021-03-26 11:39:53.836617  0.859282
2021-03-26 12:39:53.836617  0.508541

               Count
2021-03-25  6.784191
2021-03-26  8.121653
```

How can I create this dataframe where the daily values have been input, either replacing the original Count or as an additional column:

```
                               Count DayCount
2021-03-25 11:39:53.836617  0.198908 6.784191
2021-03-25 12:39:53.836617  0.527821 6.784191
2021-03-25 13:39:53.836617  0.188465 6.784191
2021-03-25 14:39:53.836617  0.959682 6.784191
2021-03-25 15:39:53.836617  0.259011 6.784191
2021-03-25 16:39:53.836617  0.371357 6.784191
2021-03-25 17:39:53.836617  0.378044 6.784191
2021-03-25 18:39:53.836617  0.893711 6.784191
2021-03-25 19:39:53.836617  0.117638 6.784191
2021-03-25 20:39:53.836617  0.615468 6.784191
2021-03-25 21:39:53.836617  0.967704 6.784191
2021-03-25 22:39:53.836617  0.323810 6.784191
2021-03-25 23:39:53.836617  0.982572 6.784191
2021-03-26 00:39:53.836617  0.634717 8.121653
2021-03-26 01:39:53.836617  0.649848 8.121653
2021-03-26 02:39:53.836617  0.817843 8.121653
2021-03-26 03:39:53.836617  0.085714 8.121653
2021-03-26 04:39:53.836617  0.260640 8.121653
2021-03-26 05:39:53.836617  0.957139 8.121653
2021-03-26 06:39:53.836617  0.983080 8.121653
2021-03-26 07:39:53.836617  0.433029 8.121653
2021-03-26 08:39:53.836617  0.570552 8.121653
2021-03-26 09:39:53.836617  0.854964 8.121653
2021-03-26 10:39:53.836617  0.506302 8.121653
2021-03-26 11:39:53.836617  0.859282 8.121653
2021-03-26 12:39:53.836617  0.508541 8.121653
```

Comment: btw: `hours = pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp.now(), freq='h', periods=27)` - no need for a loop or datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df['DayCount'] = df.resample('D')['Count'].transform('sum')
print(df.head())
                               Count  DayCount
2021-03-25 12:50:59.060224  0.736259  6.270077
2021-03-25 13:50:59.060224  0.127722  6.270077
2021-03-25 14:50:59.060224  0.609541  6.270077
2021-03-25 15:50:59.060224  0.062324  6.270077
2021-03-25 16:50:59.060224  0.597234  6.270077
```

EDIT: You can use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for new column filled by `datetime`s without `time`s by [`DatetimeIndex.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.normalize.html) and append to original by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df.assign(date=df.index.normalize()).join(df_d['Count'].rename('DayCount'), on='date')
print (df)
                               Count       date  DayCount
2021-03-25 12:57:21.149078  0.729902 2021-03-25  5.115658
2021-03-25 13:57:21.149078  0.646282 2021-03-25  5.115658
2021-03-25 14:57:21.149078  0.014579 2021-03-25  5.115658
2021-03-25 15:57:21.149078  0.927699 2021-03-25  5.115658
2021-03-25 16:57:21.149078  0.383802 2021-03-25  5.115658
```

Or if need add only one column use [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html):

```
df['DayCount'] = df.index.normalize().map(df_d['Count'])
```

Comment: I used sum as simple example. My function is much more complex and cannot be done within the resample. I need to push values from daily df to hourly df